# Continuity of 'derivative of a function'

Tags: calculus

I just learn one theorem which says If "$f^{'}$ exists and is monotonic on an open interval (a,b),then $f^{'}$ is continuous on (a,b)."I got the proof but now I am looking for one example in which if I relaxe the hypothesis of monotonic-ness then resulting $f^{'}$ is not continuous.I am thinking but unable to get such example. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe drop the quotes around theorem statement, as unnecessary...

Comment: If I remember right, $f(x)=x^2\sin{1/x}$ has a discontinuous derivative at $x=0$

Comment: There are lots of examples of differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives. Just search Google.